# How to deal with json data read from a database with RPC package

Tags: dart

I try to implement an API using the RPC dart package.

In all the example I found, response are build manually (ie new Response()..message = "hello").

In my case, i read JSON data from mongodb and want to return them with minimal transformation (basically picking only external properties).

The `fromRequest` of the method schema can be used to do this :

```
  class QueryResult {
    //my props
  }

  @ApiMethod(path: "myMongoQuery")
  Future<List<QueryResult>> myMongoQuery() async {
    var schema = _server.apiMap["/query/v1"].schemaMap["QueryResult"];
    var results = await coll.find();

    return results.map(schema.fromRequest).toList();
  }
```

The problem in my code is the first line (`_server.apiMap["/query/v1"].schemaMap["QueryResult"]`) it's a pure hack to retrieve the schema of my method.

I tried to use mirror to retrieve the schema in an elegant/generic way but did not succeed.

Anyone can help me on this ?

Cheers,

Nicolas

Comment: I find an easy way to have access to the response schema:

    `var querySchema = new ApiParser().parseSchema(reflectClass(QueryResult ), false);`